# How to verify a .sig for a .deb package (for keybase.io)

Tags: debian, gnupg, linux-mint

am currently installing keybase.io on Linux Mint 64bit and although I know how to verify an asc fingerprint, I am struggling to check the .deb file for keybase.io ...

As per: https://keybase.io/docs/the_app/install_linux

I'd like to install the 64-bit deb version.

There are details for an .asc and a fingerprint (which work, I can check that via gpg --with-fingerprint code_signing_key.asc ) ... but what do I do with the .sig to check the actual installation file (https://prerelease.keybase.io/keybase_amd64.deb)?

Apologies if this is really basic but am only just getting comfortable with gpg keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [this](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x135.html) you're looking for

```
gpg --verify keybase_amd64.deb.sig keybase_amd64.deb
```

You can also leave off the second argument (the .deb file) and it'll assume you're trying to verify a file named everything to the left of ".sig" in the .sig filename, in the same directory.

Comment: Worked, thanks!... though you need to import the asc with: gpg --import code_signing_key.asc